# How to compair NString when it is converted from NSArray in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I am new in iOS. And I am facing a problem in a code

```
array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        array =[responsedict valueForKey:@"Type"];
        NSLog(@"Type Array =%@",array);
 for (int i =0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    if (array.count>0)
    {
       typeString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSLog(@"Type String =%@",typeString);
    }
 }
```

I am getting the value in String as

```
Type String =1
Type String =2
```

Now I need to compair the String in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if ([typeString isEqual:@"1"]) {
            cell.IBTiconlbl.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
if ([typeString isEqual:@"2"]) {
            cell.IBTiconlbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
```

But it convert the textcolour only in readColor not in blue colour. String contain both the value 1 and 2. I need to convert the text colour in blue when string value is 1 and in red when string value is 2. But it only perform the one operation.

Comment: use like this `if ([typeString isEqualToString:@"1"])` to compare strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to convert the whole array into `NSString` this will save the code optimization time a bit you can do this by checking the object using `indexPath.row` and take action accordingly see below code:

```
if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] isEqualToString:@"1"]){
        cell.IBTiconlbl.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}else if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] isEqualToString:@"2"]){
        cell.IBTiconlbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}else{
        // code for else part here
}
```

Comment: your Code Shows an error [__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000013

Comment: okay see my updated and now ..previously array returning number that's y you getting en error ..

Comment: Your Code is perfect. Thanks for help you save my day.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
if ([typeString isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
    cell.IBTiconlbl.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
} else if ([typeString isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
    cell.IBTiconlbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
} else {
    cell.IBTiconlbl.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get a book about iOS programming and study it.

- Problem 1:

  In the first line you create an NSMutableArray and assign it to array. In the next line you overwrite array. Creating the NSMutableArray was completely pointless.
- Problem 2:

  You are using the method valueForKey. Unless you have read the documentation of valueForKey, you understood it, and you have a valid reason to use valueForKey and not objectForKey, you should use objectForKey or subscript syntax. So either [responseDict objectForKey:@"Type"] or better responseDict [@"Type"].
- Problem 3:

  You are not checking the result in any way, so your app will crash very soon if you have an object that is not an array. And if you assign it to an NSMutableArray, then it will crash as soon as you try to modify it, because it is very unlikely to be an NSMutableArray.
- Problem 4:

  The "if (array.count > 0)" is obviously pointless.
- Problem 5:

  You are making yours and everyone else's life very hard by not using the proper loop syntax. for (id item in array) is much shorter and will run much faster than your code.
- Problem 6:

  Why on earth is typeString mutable?
- Problem 7:

  You seem to have no idea what kind of object is stored in the array. Is it a number, is it a string? You should really know that and compare accordingly.
- Problem 8:

  You should absolutely not be parsing some data in cellForRowAtIndexPath. That is monstrous. Take your responseDict, define a class that can represent your response data, parse it *once* into appropriate data, including all the error checking that you have, and then cellForRowAtIndexPath can access the data.

Comment: when I am not using if (array.count>0) and the array is nil the app get crash.So to prevent is from crash I am using if (array.count>0).

Comment: array is just an object of NSMutableArray.